# trying to create a script with timestamp

Tags: bash

I'm fairly new to bash scripting.
I'm trying to create a directory with a timestamp and then cd into the directory.
I'm able to create a directory and can cd into it the directory with one command.

mkdir "build" && cd "build"

I can create the directory with data then cd into it.

mkdir `date '+%m%d%y'` && cd `date '+%m%d%y'` I am able to create this dir and cd into it with one command.

Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# mkdir $(date +%F) && cd $(date +%F)

 mkdir build_`date '+%m%d%y'` && cd build_`date '+%m%d%y'`
```

I need to create the directory with build_`date '+%m%d%y'` in the title then cd into that folder.
I've looked online but am unable to come up with a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

build_dir="build_$(date '+%m%d%y')"

mkdir $build_dir && cd $build_dir
```

Comment: It will create the directory but won't cd into it.

Comment: sure it does, within the context of the script. It won't place the callers terminal in that directory if that's what your expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to name your Folders YYYY.MM.DD like build_2019.11.21

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY="build_$(date '+%Y.%m.%d')"
if [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    # checking if $DIRECTORY doesn't exist.
    mkdir $DIRECTORY
fi
cd $DIRECTORY
touch testfile
```

Comment: That script will create the directory but won't cd into it.

Comment: @TrentFolk check it out, it works, it creates a file in it

Comment: I wasn't using source. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that uses `/usr/bin/env bash` and the builtin command `printf` instead of `/bin/date`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

date="$(printf '%(%m%d%y)T' -1)"
[[ -d build_"${date}" ]] || mkdir build_"${date}"
cd build_"${date}"

# do something useful here
# ...
```

However, changing directory in a script (subshell) is not much use on its own, as your current working directory (`$PWD`) will be the same after the script exits.

If you want to have the current shell session change into the new directory, use a shell function.

```sh
mkbuild() {
  date="$(printf '%(%m%d%y)T' -1)"
  [[ -d build_"${date}" ]] || mkdir build_"${date}"
  cd build_"${date}"
}
```

Then run it:

```
$ echo $PWD
/tmp
$ mkbuild
$ echo $PWD
/tmp/build_112119
```